# Add div in HTML after <body ...> in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Requirement: 
add custom html after body tag in string

I solved with htmlagilitypack like this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(customStringWithHtmlContent)
 HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());
 // Create new node from newcontent
 HtmlNode newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div>" + someStringWithAdditionalContent + "</div>");
 // Get body node
 HtmlNode body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
 if (body != null)
    {// Add new node as first child of body
      body.PrependChild(newNode);
    }
 var docContent = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Looks good but in some html pages, html structure is changed, closed div tags are moved and html is renderend ugly

second solution:

```
 if (sb.ToString().Contains("<body>"))
    {
      sb.Replace("<body>", "<body><div>" + someStringWithAdditionalContent + "</div>");
    }
```

Looks good, but is not a solution for body with attributes like

```
<body style="someAttr:value ..." ...>
```

some ideas ? other solutions?

Comment: Your first solution looks good. Do you have a HTML example that is not working with it?

Answer (score 0):

RegEx? There's probably a more elegant way but the basic idea:

```
    string input = "<body style=\"someAttr\"><tag>sdsdsa</tag></body>";
    Regex Pattern = new Regex(@"(<body.*?>)(.*?)(<\/body>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    var updatedText = Pattern.Replace(input, match =>
    {
        string newMatch = match.Groups[2].Value;
        string newContent = "<div>" + "someStringWithAdditionalContent" + "</div>";
        return match.Groups[1].Value + newContent + newMatch + match.Groups[3].Value;
    });
    Console.WriteLine(updatedText);
```

Output:

```
<body style="someAttr"><div>someStringWithAdditionalContent</div><tag>sdsdsa</tag></body>
```